# Automation of Supportsave command for Brocade switches

Tags: bash, automation

I am looking for automation of Supportsave command in Brocade switches.
I am creating a bash script.
Issue is this command prompts for multiple parameters when run.

```
***:admin> supportsave
This command collects RASLOG, TRACE, supportShow, core file, FFDC data
and then transfer them to a FTP/SCP/SFTP server or a USB device.
This operation can take several minutes.
NOTE: supportSave will transfer existing trace dump file first, then
automatically generate and transfer latest one. There will be two trace dump
files transferred after this command.
OK to proceed? (yes, y, no, n): [no] y
 
Host IP or Host Name: 

User Name: 

Password:

Protocol (ftp | scp | sftp): ftp

Remote Directory:
```

how to pass all this parameters in bash script?

I have only one idea about this -

```
echo Y | command
```

but here many inputs we need to pass for different prompts.

Comment: if you can see that `echo "yes" | command` is working for the first prompt, then maybe you can get `printf "yes\nHOSTNAME\nUSERNAME\nftp\n/path/to/remote\n" | command` to work. You may need to try `\r\n`, or even just `\r`. You may need to break them up and add `sleep 1` in between each `echo something | command ; sleep 1`. There is also the `expect` utility that is designed for such cases, but it has a learning curve. Good luck.

Comment: `expect`, mentioned by @shellter, is the canonical tool for this sort of automation. There are similar facilities available in other languages if you're not looking to learn TCL (e.g., there is [PExpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for Python).

Comment: I went through brocade cli documentation and got this - this saved me from the interactive prompt  
 supportsave -u <hostuser>-p <hostpass> -h <hostip> -d AUTOMAT -l ftp -n